# Python: finding content in dynamically generated HTML

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get stock options prices from [this website](http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/pt_br/servicos/market-data/consultas/mercado-de-derivativos/precos-referenciais/precos-referenciais-bm-f-premios-de-opcoes/) based on the series code (for example FMM1), but the content is dynamically generated after the page loads and my python selenium script is not able to extract the correct source code, and therefore does not find it. When I inspect element, [I can find it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEZUs.png) but not when I click on "view source code".

This is my code:

```
# Here, we open the website for options prices in Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/pt_br/servicos/market-data/consultas/mercado-de-derivativos/precos-referenciais/precos-referenciais-bm-f-premios-de-opcoes/")

# Since the page is populated by JavaScript code *after* loading the page, we 
# tell the browser to wait 10 seconds before getting the source html code
time.sleep(10)
html_file = driver.page_source # gets the html source of the page
print(html_file)
```

I have also tried the following, but it did not work:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,
              "divContainerIframeBmf")))
```

Comment: From the link, I wasn't able to find an element with `id="divContainerIframeBmf"` when I manually inspected the page.

Comment: It is two lines above the "large-12 columns" class (I have also tried with this one). But to be honest this doesn't really matter, it was just one ID that I chose to wait for. What I really need is to capture the price of the stock option.

Comment: I see. I've encountered the same issue as you. From preliminary research on different tools to use for responsive webpages, I came across the [Galen framework](http://galenframework.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this after the page loads

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe"))
```

and continue performing your operations on the page.

Comment: Thank you!! This has worked perfectly, tks a bunch!!